# VS Extensions VSIX Is there a way to get the position of multiple cursors in a VSIX command?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, envdte

Currenty I'm able to get the position of the main/first cursor using the following code:

```
(dte.ActiveWindow.Selection as TextSelection).ActivePoint.AbsoluteCharOffset
```

But when the user have multiple selections (ex: using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>), is it possible to get all cursors positions/selections in a VSIX command?